# How does Unity pick which sprite atlas to load?

Tags: unity, spritesheet

I plan to use sprite atlases for my 2D game. All my animation is sprite animation so I'm going to use sprite atlases for my characters' sprites.

My question is, if I put the same sprite in two different atlases, how does Unity decide which atlas to load?

EX:
I have a sprite atlas per level that contains the background for that level.  Sometimes, there's space left over in the atlas.  So, if I want to put a sprite, which already exists in another atlas, in the empty space for that level's atlas, how does Unity know not to load both atlases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It picks one randomly. In fact it gives a warning when you have a sprite in multiple atlases, telling you to not do that.

See here for relevant details: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpriteAtlasScenarios.html

You’re looking specifically at scenario 3 on that page:

> **Scenario 3: One Sprite in two Sprite Atlases**
>
> 1. Sprite Atlas A and Sprite Atlas B both include Sprite 1 in their Objects for Packing lists.
> 2. Both Sprite Atlas A and Sprite Atlas B have Include in Build enabled.
> 3. Both Sprite Atlases have different Texture output settings in this example.
> 4. Result: The Project’s published build includes both Sprite Atlases. ***Unity randomly chooses which Texture to render Sprite 1 with,
>    in an internal process that is out of your control.***

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing that.  I don't know how I missed that!